# How to view Flutter app Dart stacktrace with Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, obfuscation, crashlytics-android

I have a flutter app that uses some Android-specific code (Java/Kotlin). In "app/build.gradle" i do have `firebaseCrashlytics/mappingFileUploadEnabled true`:

```
    release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.googleplaySigningConfig

            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
                unstrippedNativeLibsDir "build/app/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib"
            }

            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
        }
```

Also note in root "build.gradle":

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
```

I build the app using `flutter build appbundle` and i believe it should trigger uploading of obfuscation maps to Firebase crashlytics.

However i get smth like:
[image]
which makes me think Firebase Crashlytics was unable to find deobfuscated code for obfuscated using the uploaded mapping.

What can i do or check?

PS. After reading the error message more carefully i realized it's actually Dart code where the error happens (not my Java code). However, i'm still confused why i can't see Dart stacktrace instead.

Comment: have the same issue